# App break after splash but visual studio still running

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to debug IOS app on Xamarin forms project , app is running but break after splash appear
every time i open the app it breaks
No errors and i tried all the solutions and nothing works

vs 2019
xamarin forms 4.7

this is the log

```
Aug  4 15:13:28 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   Ignoring trigger com.apple.das.apppolicy.appchanged because conditions are deteriorating
Aug  4 15:13:28 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:28 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:28 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   Attempting to suspend based on triggers: (     "com.apple.das.apppolicy.appchanged" )
Aug  4 15:13:28 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"client getting effective client name", "bundleId":"com.apple.AppStore", "bundlePath":""}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd(CoreLocation) {"msg":"CLInternalGetAuthorizationStatus", "event":"activity"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"client getting effective client name", "bundleId":"", "bundlePath":"\134/System\134/Library\134/LocationBundles\134/AppSuggestions.bundle"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd(CoreLocation) {"msg":"CLInternalGetAuthorizationStatus", "event":"activity"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  53  sharingd    Skipping request for enabled: YES, state: PoweredOn, shouldStart: NO, scanForCopyPaste: YES, scanForHandoff: YES
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(UserActivity)   notifyBestAppChanged:(null) UASuggestedActionType=0 <private>/<private> opts=(null) when=Tue Aug  4 15:13:26 2020 confidence=0 from=<private>/<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  124 useractivityd(Sharing)  client process changing types to scan for to Handoff, CopyPaste
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"state transition", "event":"state_transition", "state":"DaemonClient", "id":"0x105681c00", "property":"lifecycle", "old":"0x105681c00", "new":"0x0"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard disconnected
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   CLGyroBiasEstimator,SPUEnabled,0,BuildingGYTT,0,NumClients,0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"CLConnection::handleDisconnection", "event":"activity"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   #Warning Location connection invalid!
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) {"msg":"CLGyroBiasEstimatorClientRemote::unregisterWithGyroBiasEstimatorPrivate", "event":"activity", "client":"0x281b87560"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   Reporting events to Powerlog <private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) L2 Metrics on ifname en0: rssi: -70 (txFrames/txReTx/txFail) 0/0/0 -> (was/is) 0/0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   PowerLog Update: Discretionary energy consumed since last read: 0.00
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   PowerLog Update: received consumption report: <private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  127 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)   PowerLog Update: Using UUID based reporting
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Failed to find process for com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) NBSM Current state: normal, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0, eligible for broken but constraints unsatisfied (0,0)
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) NBSM Eligible to go to broken
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) NBSM Current state: normal, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp: Foreground: false
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Entry, display name com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp uuid (null) pid 534 isFront 0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Continue with bundle name com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp, is front 0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  118 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) 534 com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp: Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(WiFiPicker) WIFI PICKER [com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp]: isProcessLaunch: 0,    isForegroundActivation: 0,     isForegroundDeactivation: 1

Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard (0x105681c00) is subscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageGyroBiasEstimation
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"kCLConnectionMessageGyroBiasEstimation", "event":"activity", "this":"0x105681c00", "registrationRequired":0, "registrationReceived":0}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard connected
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   #Warning PAUSE: BATCH: '<private>' (<private>, <private>) started in unexpected state: <private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"state transition", "event":"state_transition", "state":"DaemonClient", "id":"0x105681c00", "property":"clientName", "old":"", "new":"com.apple.springboard"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:16667 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set batch interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  52  backboardd(IOKit)   0x1000002ee: set report interval:20000 client:<private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  73  CommCenter  #I FBSDisplayLayoutUpdateHandler: 5. app got notification state: new counter=71
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  73  CommCenter  #I ActivationObserver: notifyAboutFrontAppChange : app: <private>; pid: 0; net: 0
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  73  CommCenter  #I FBSDisplayLayoutUpdateHandler: update start
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  73  CommCenter  #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp: (null)
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  55  locationd   {"msg":"state transition", "event":"state_transition", "state":"DaemonClient", "id":"0x105681c00", "property":"lifecycle", "old":"0x0", "new":"0x105681c00"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard reconfigured lock button: <SBMutableHardwareButtonGestureParameters: 0x280e83d00; maximumPressCount: 1; longPressTimeInterval: 2.50s; multiplePressTimeInterval: 0.30s>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  23  mediaserverd(CoreMedia) -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp with pid '534' is now Terminated. Background entitlement: NO LongFormVideoApp: NO
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10cd9ba10; Selaheltelmeez. (com.selaheltelmeezcompany.Selaheltelmeezapp); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x2814ab870; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)> {
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  58  assertiond  -[BKAssertion dealloc] - <0x151d168f0>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  58  assertiond  [Selaheltelmeez.:534] No clients remain.
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  58  assertiond  [Selaheltelmeez.:534] Removing client: <BKProcessInfoServerClient: 0x151e4f2f0; pid: 48>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Root transaction complete: <SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction: 0x10a568ba0>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Nudging home screen window orientation because icon rotation changed.
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Enabling home screen icon rotation for reason: SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) {"msg":"Sending cached messages to daemon", "event":"activity"}
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard Front display did change: (null)
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(SpringBoardFoundation)  Evaluate: making new window key: <SBHomeScreenWindow: 0x10197bab0>, for reason: popped window was key
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(SpringBoardFoundation)  Pop (wasKey=YES, reason=caller requested): <private>
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard removing status bar settings assertion after 2.563069 seconds: <SBAppStatusBarSettingsAssertion: 0x281754270> {
Aug  4 15:13:26 Yousefs-iPad    Notice  48  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) {"msg":"CLGyroBiasEstimatorClientRemote::onWatchdogTimerExpiry", "event":"activity", "client":"0x281b87560"}
```

any help for this issue? No crashing or exceptions thrown also no break points called

Comment: For this project, have you test on another device? Does it work well on Android device or emulator?

Comment: yes , it works on android but another device not

Comment: It seems the project is okay. The log does not mentioned about the error. Try to create a new project and test with the ios emulator. If you still get the error, i guess the emulator cause it.